# docker build --no-cache=true still builds with cache?

Tags: caching, docker

I build an image:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7
```

build command:

```
$ docker build -t my-image:1.0 .
```

Now I make a second image (which is based on the original dockerfile)
Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7
RUN yum install -y mysql
```

I build with the `--no-cache` option on true

```
$ docker build --no-cache=true -t my-image:1.1 .

Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM centos:7
 ---> 970633036444
Step 2 : xx
```

it seems to use the cache. And also when I try to delete my-image:1.0:

```
docker rmi 970633036444
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 970633036444 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It uses the [docker centos7 image downloaded from Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/).

That will always be the case, cache or no cache.
The `--no-cache` would apply to the directive/step *after* `FROM`.

Comment: Additional reading material: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22832